# How do I unclog my AC drainage line

Tags: air-conditioning, drainage, clog

I live in a condo with an in-home AC/heat pump. This morning we noticed that it was dripping water, and when we took off the front panel we could see standing water in the run-off tray. It was pretty clear that there was gunk (probably built-up dust) in the bottom of the tray, so we assume there's a bunch of it clogging the PVC piping too.

**What is the best way to clean this out?** We have one snake tool, but unfortunately it only reaches to about the top of the U-bend. I read that Drano is not a good idea, because without water pressure from above, it could sit in the U-bend and corrode the pipes. We poured about a cup of vinegar in this morning and are going to let that sit all day to see how it does. Is there anything else we can do if this doesn't work? We don't really want to have to call a plumber if it's just a clog job.

***Update:*** All the vinegar drained through. Filled it again and it's a slow drain, though better than it was before. Hopefully a few runs of this will do the trick.

Here's some pictures to give you a better idea what I'm dealing with. The left shows the PVC piping. The right shows the coils, with the drainage tray underneath. The water pools underneath that lowest coil.

[image: ac_drain]

Comment: There are at least a couple dozen versions of this question on this site.  Bleach is your best bet, but will work best if you can at least get a small flow started.  Is the other end of the tube/pipe accessable?   Once you get it unplugged remember to run bleach water down it every year.

Comment: @Tyson No, it's not really accessible. It comes off of the unit, has a small U-bend, then goes straight into the wall. There's a screw connection to the unit itself, but it looks like it's glued on pretty well. We didn't want to attempt to remove it and then break it or not be able to get it back on.

Comment: If you have access to the end of the discharge pipe use a wet vac to suck the stuff out of the pipe.

Comment: @d.george We did try that, and were able to get some of the standing water out of the tray. Unfortunately there's so much stuff in the way that it's impossible to get a good connection on the pipe itself. I can see if I can get a picture when I get home tonight.

Comment: @Tyson Also, I imagine using bleach after we've used vinegar is a *bad* idea.

Comment: @Tyson I'd double check that. Everything on google says that vinegar+beach = chlorine gas. https://www.thoughtco.com/mixing-bleach-and-vinegar-609281

Comment: I deleted, I've done that tho...

Comment: I would not use vinegar in any way that would allow it to get on the evaporator coil. It could cause corrosion, although once the unit is running again condensate would probably dilute the vinegar and rinse it away.

Comment: Some condensate lines have an upward opening T fitting in an initial horizontal run which one normally keeps plugged with a rubber stopper, but which allows bleach to be poured into the condensate line, and also would allow suction with a shop vac. The bleach could flow in both directions. What is the material of your condensate line--copper or plastic (usually PVC)?

Comment: @JimStewart There wasn't an upward T-fitting, but I do recall seeing some something with horizontal plugs at the connector. However, one of the "plugs" was just a wadded up bit of plastic bag, so there's a strong chance it wasn't installed properly, like many thing in our condo. I'll take a closer look when I get home. The pipes are PVC, and the tray and intake are all below the coils, so no worry about getting solvents on the coils.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution to this problem is to install a drain system that allows for easy inspection and cleaning.  Here is an example of "the right way" to plumb that:

[image: Proper AC condensation drain]